# Need help on the Need of Responsive website

Tags: jquery-mobile, responsive-design, responsive

I have created a fully functional good looking website but it is not responsive as of now, I tried to make it responsive but the code is not developed that way.

So Now I am thinking to go for an alternative. i:e Jquery Mobile.

So there will be two websites one is for desktop and one is for mobile device(to be coded newly in jquery mobile). Whenever user visit with any mobile device, I will redirect the user to the mobile version.

So I just wanted to confirm if it could be the good practice or not. Will it impact SEO or Would there be any problem for the website in future if I go that way?

Answer (score 0):

I have several sites that use jQuery Mobile and they all rank well and pass the [Google Mobile Friendly Test](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/mobile-friendly), so I don't think you need to be too concerned about SEO being affected if you have two sites.

Having standalone mobile sites does have some advantages, for example you can make the page weight of your mobile sites lighter without any complicated javascript.

One to the downsides is that you'll have two versions on the same site to maintain. The only reason I still have some jQuery Mobile sites is that they are older and were designed before responsive web design was cross-browser reliable.

> So I just wanted to confirm if it could be the good practice or not?

You can go either way. I found jQuery Mobile easy to implement and it has been very reliable and low maintenance. Personally I go for responsive design now, but I'm sure you'll find plenty of developers that prefer using standalone mobile sites and jQuery Mobile.

Good luck!